# How can I know what _root means in this context?

Tags: flash, actionscript, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse-engineering good old online Flash game. It's encrypts some user init data in RC4. But that's not that painful problem. How can I know what _root means in this context? I can't recompile this SWF to use trace(). Help me please. Code that I partly do not understand is below.  I don't understand how server gets _root contents to encrypt data. Decrypting function converts second argument to string.

```
   function LoadServerXML(path, callback, data)
   {
      var _loc5_ = new utilites.LoadXML();
      if(data)
      {
         _loc5_.setAndLoadChannels(data,path);
      }
      else
      {
         _loc5_.getChannels(path);
      }
      var _loc7_ = function(event)
      {
         event.cdata = {};
         var _loc6_ = event.target.firstChild;
         var _loc2_ = _loc6_.childNodes;
         for(var _loc5_ in _loc2_)
         {
            if(_loc2_[_loc5_].nodeName == "cdata")
            {
               var _loc3_ = new XML(utilites.UTF8.Decode(utilites.Crypt.DecryptH(_loc2_[_loc5_].attributes.value,_root))).firstChild; // <= here
               _loc2_[_loc5_].removeNode();
               event.cdata[_loc3_.nodeName] = _loc3_;
            }
         }
      };
      _loc5_.addEventListener("onResult",$.FnChain(null,_loc7_,callback));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

_root is a special keyword in AS2, which I'm guessing this project was written in.

_root is the base object, which as a concept was replaced by "stage" more or less in AS3.  It's background color, for instance is the background color of the entire swf movie.

A lot of folks used it as an effective means of static access as well, as _root.foo could be accessed as a global variable from anywhere.  Since it was an object you could access any variables on it from any scope.

I hope that helps.

Think of it as the "main" object of the movie.